# Why is BM25 score results are negative for all the documents?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, nlp, search-engine

I have been trying to calculate BM25 score to find relevant and non-relevant documents from a set of documents based on the query. As it turns out my BM25 score is coming out to be negative for all the documents because of either length of the document or number of documents. The code is in python. The set of documents are xml files.

****For example:

the number before the semicolon is the document id and the number after the semi-colon is BM25 score based on the query.

The output is as follow in python:****

For query "Research documents on the pros/cons of government-supported school vouchers for private or religious schools"

bm25 -->  {'47424': -15.148270578009287, '59301': -4.5324888278916955, '51441': -6.39047920340723, '35782': -12.439912866021055, '6409': -14.577866844394313, '70619': -17.00481043343906, '44597': -8.697203569753626, '73731': -5.178938184315641, '56686': -15.217341163205859, '75558': -13.864972462927318, '6386': -15.063892406359518, '50516': -15.224423885623839, '53259': -15.251308584218336, '53364': -15.66416744135934, '7914': -5.66450911939087, '32528': -16.092842615677846, '16723': -10.120903791415753, '86068': -15.109324552334709, '67169': -16.25963854937583, '41521': -14.689271200861244, '25029': -10.542716008819404, '32963': -15.995234645822308, '49023': -5.128845432659929, '46632': -4.522709302815306, '76481': -15.331654599460377, '19526': -16.5397158773958, '68829': -6.237632920251847, '49731': -16.64556902599432, '61487': -15.777496075315927, '16841': -4.970159012101008, '6399': -16.14724012989677, '55974': -16.679111714509364, '76556': -14.37904634631273, '61644': -9.167501264772618, '8085': -15.048433817371734, '55891': -8.227333733937748, '3648': -16.5003155647673, '70606': -16.840470957025445, '64336': -4.2650402909943, '31281': -15.991922110559575, '2800': -14.793472384723657, '67135': -14.008735870771446, '41355': -14.200897078737842, '70854': -16.398911831821696}

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to your IDF function, which is normally computed by IDF = log((N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)).
This results in a negative value for terms appearing in more than half of the corpus documents.
Since you multiply this IDF value with the other part of the BM25 formula, your overall BM25 result will become negative too.